# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when updating/saving images

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm displaying the image on a datagradview from my database using this code:

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT custImage from cust_tbl"

Try
    dgUsers.Rows.Clear()
    con.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read
        dgUsers.Rows.Add(reader(0))
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

To open the update form, I'm using the cellclick funtion with this code inside:

```vb
Dim update As frmUpdateCust = frmUpdateCust
Dim img = ImageFromBytes(dgUsers.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)
update.image.Image = img
update.Show()
update.BringToFront()
```

However, if a user clicks a cell which prompts the update form to open and then clicks the Update button, I'm getting

> "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Here's my code for saving/updating the image:

```vb
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
image.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim photo_aray(ms.Length) As Byte
ms.Position = 0
ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length)

Dim ff As New SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.Image)
ff.Value = photo_aray
cmd.Parameters.Add(ff)
```

It works perfectly when the user uploads a new or the same image using Open File Dialog. I only started getting serious with vb.net last month and still trying to learn more. Hoping for positive responses. :)

Comment: Not sure what causes you error, but your array is one byte too big. In VB.NET you define an array's _**last index**_ rather than _**its capacity**_, so your array should be declared like: `Dim photo_aray(ms.Length - 1) As Byte`.

Comment: HOWEVER reading to the array manually is unnecessary since the memory stream has got a [**`ToArray()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can replace your `ms.Read(...)` code with: `Dim photo_aray() As Byte = ms.ToArray()`.